# is this php code malicious and how can i protect my hosting?

Tags: php, security, webserver, plesk

I host a website for a client and we have been asked to host some extra images for the clients other third party website shop.

So i created a secondary FTP account that had its root set to some sub folder on the hosting.

The client had the web designer who was building out the layout for this external website place all the images in this FTP space.

Today i noticed some warning notices in the error_log and noticed it was coming from a php file that was also within this FTP space.

The contents of the PHP was this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$file1=trim($_REQUEST['f1']);
$read1=file_get_contents($file1);
$read1 = rawurlencode($read1);
echo "document.write(unescape(\"$read1\"))";
?>
```

When i first read the code i couldn't figure out why it was in the FTP space or what it did but i started playing around by adding some paths to the f1 parameter to see what response was returned and i found that i could output my wordpress installs wp-config.php file that is back a folder from this FTP's root folder.

e.g by running this parameter through the php script. it outputted the contents of my config:
domain.com?f1=/mnt/storage/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/wordpress/wp-config.php

now I am just trying to figure out if this code could have been placed in the FTP storage for any other reason than to be malicious?

How can i protect my files from being read like this when giving out FTP access to a subfolder on a hosting?

Thanks.

Comment: Just don't give anyone root, but you...

Comment: PHP files **will** get executed, but you can prevent it to make damage on your server. Just set up adequate permissions and do **not** share a root account with other users.

Comment: Read `chown` and `chmod` on the internet (if you are using linux on your server)

Comment: I did create a secondary ftp user. What do you mean by "root account"?

Comment: If you're using linux, and using a FTP server on your host, that ftp is probably 'root' by default. **Don't** share this account with anyone, but you. Set up a new one. There are plenty of tutorials on the internet on how to set up a new user for your FTP account.

Comment: But i did create a second user specifically for their FTP account. I use Plesk to create hostings and new FTP user accounts.

Comment: Did you set appropriate permissions on files and folders?

Comment: No. So i need to look into removing read rights for their user for all folders but the subfolder that the FTP space was set up to have access to.

Comment: Exactly... If you can, try `chmod` all folders to `660` or something alike, then only root should have access to it.

Comment: ok Thats a bit hard on plesk because plesk uses its own user to manage the files from the plesk user interface. Plesk also creates a user for the web hosting subscription (the one i use for FTP) and then there is also root but we dont touch root unless we have to. I think i need to figure out how to specifically set permissions on a single user so i can remove read rights only for this extra FTP user.

Comment: Look at that: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/plesk/plesk-administration/how-to-change-file-permissions-in-plesk

Comment: its apache that is reading the file not the ftp user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script opens the file passed in the GET parameter, reads it, URL encodes it and then sends it to the browser wrapped in some JavaScript that de-codes it client-side.

The script is virtually guaranteed to be written with malicious intent. While outputting the contents of a file may have legitimate uses, the (very basic) obfuscation technique used here pushes it over the edge of any reasonable doubt.

The FTP root of your user may be protected, but it seems that you do not run separate PHP interpreters for your users. That means that any user who can write code to their webspace and executes it through the PHP interpreter may run code as whatever user the PHP interpreter is running at. Since PHP necessarily needs to read the wordpress configuration, there is little you can do to secure the current setup.

Ideally, you will want to isolate every user in their own chroot or docker instance with their own PHP interpreter. Short of that, you should absolutely not allow FTP access or any other methods for uploading files on your system as the security model is simply not designed to withstand this level of user-access.

Comment: Thanks. I think i will create a subdomain for the images and then just turn off PHP for this subdomain.

Comment: I deleted the PHP file and noticed some errors showing on the external shop website. From the errors in console I can confirm that they are using the php script to pull in the contents of html files that are stored on the FTP space.

Comment: So i do need php and i do need this scrip to work. I just need to stop the script from having access to files in the hosting. to do this I changed the open_basedir to use {DOCROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/} this means that the php script can only have access to files on the subdomain.